# Appflood ads banner size and position

Tags: android, ads

Hi I am developing an app on android and I am midway to the finishline, after reading some articles, opinions on the net, I found appflood as the most preferred ads. As I implementing the ads, I can not find a way on how to put the ads banner just staying on the bottom part of my activity not a popup, but just a display at the bottom part.

there is no tutorial found in the net, not included in both integration guide and javadoc on appflood. Please help me .

so the question is : how can I implement an ads that only displays, stay on the bottom part of my activity (screen) and not by popups.  Also do ads really needs an internet connection to be loaded ? thank you in advance  :D

I used this code but it's a popup. I place it on onCreate

I change the keys for confidentiality . I believe it's ok.

```
AppFlood.initialize(this, "sample key here", "sample secret key here", AppFlood.AD_PANEL);

AppFlood.showPanel(this, 2);
```

thanks.
-ralph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work for AppFlood and thought I'd lend a hand. By the way, I'm glad to hear that you're giving AppFlood a whirl :)

Now onto the troubleshooting:

**1.** To troubleshoot the issue that you're having based on the code that you've displayed there, what you're using is AppFlood's panel ad format: AppFlood.AD_PANEL.

This is a different ad format from our banners. If you'd like to initialize the banner ad format, you can use the following code:

```
AppFlood.initialize(this, "sample key here", "sample secret key here", AppFlood.AD_ALL);
```

Note: AFBannerView is a subclass of View and you can use this like a View

**2.** To answer your second question: Yes, you do need an Internet connection to be loaded.

I hope that helps. Feel free to reach out to me at francis@papayamobile.com if you have any further questions.

And if you'd like to dig around for further information about our ad formats or additional info about monetizing your mobile app, you can check out our "[App Monetization Guides, Tips and Strategies](http://appflood.com/a/app-monetization-guides-tips-and-strategies)."

FYI: You might also be interested in checking out our [interstitial ad format](http://appflood.com/blog/interstitial-ads-generate-the-highest-earnings), which tends to generate the most revenue for developers.

Comment: thank you that really helps. and ill email you right away. also ive read about your "interstitial ad" but not on game dev, im on app, idk if thats ok, anyway thanks alot. Ill send you an email. :D

Comment: No worries. We're not on Reddit :D